# Reset Button Equivalent Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="reset"/>
```

Can we have write a equivalent action in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) method on a form element.

Comment: I was tempted not to up-vote this and just move on because of the "duh" nature of the question, but who knows... some js newbie might see this and need to know it.